# How to select points within a certain distance from a line?

Tags: qgis-plugins, point, polygon-creation, select-by-location, qgis-2.10

I have a file with a points layer and a lines layer. I would like to select only the points that lay within certain distance (a couple of meters) of the lines.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Or should I create a new polygone layer wich forms a kind of buffer around te lines and then use the select bij location tool?

How can I create such a layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using ArcGIS or not but if you are and I dont know if this is the most ideal answer but yes, run the buffer tool and create a buffer around your line at whatever distance you want.  Then run the select by spatial location and select all points that are completely contained by the newly created buffer layer.  This will give you the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

I ***strongly*** suggest the method mentioned by yourself and @user3338197 as it's probably the simplest.

Another method to calculate the distance from a point to its nearest line involves first having to convert your line layer to points using **Convert lines to points** from SAGA (in the *Processing Toolbox*). Select *Yes* for the Insert Additional Points option and use a very low value for the Insert Distance (such as *0.01*, note that this is measured in metres). This adds a point every *0.01 m* so the lower this value is, the more accurate you will be when finding the nearest distance.

Now you can use the **Distance to nearest hub** tool which calculates the distance (in metres, feet, layer units etc.) from a source to the destination layer.

You will have the option of exporting another point shapefile which will have an attribute containing the distances of each point to its nearest line:

[image: Distance to nearest hub]

You can then use the *Field Calculator* or *Select by expression* tool to only show/select points within x metres:

```
"HubDist" < x
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Heres an upvote for a new method i didnt know about!

Comment: @user3338197 - Haha thank you but it wasn't necessary! You learn something new everyday (I always do!). But I like your method as I have used it in the past and has always worked a treat =)

Comment: Yup, one of the things I love about GIS is there is definitely more than one way to skin the cat!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but unfortunately I could not repeat all the steps you mentioned above. I have now created a distance to nearest hub  layer, but I can not select the points within, say, 3 meters with the Field calculator. I have selected Hub Distance as input layer and gave the output field a name. And then in in the expression field I have typed: "HubDist" < 3. This way it selects all the points. But how do I select a unit, in this case meters? Also, I can not find the other method: Select by expression, where can I find this?

Comment: If your CRS uses distance instead of degrees and you select the _Measurement Unit_ to be metres (or meters) from the interface as shown in the image, all distances calculated should be in metres. You can find the _Select by expression_ tool from the **Processing Toolbox** (check if the **Processing** plugin is enabled from the toolbar: _Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins_). When enabled, you should find **Processing** in the toolbar which you can then access the toolbox. This contains a huge list of tools.

Comment: It worked, but now the distance to nearest hub is calculated to the middle of the line (like you can see in the picture I attached to the original problem description). Is there a way where I can calculate the distance of the shortest possible route to the line?

Comment: @D.Sanders - Apologies! I completely forgot that if you use a line layer with the _Distance to nearest hub_ tool, it will use the centre of the line as the reference. You would need to convert your line layer to points and use this to calculate the distance between your original point layer. I've edited the post. I strongly advise using the buffer method as it is a lot easier in my opinion unless you require a distance attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much, I started over the whole project from scratch, because not all layers where in the same crs, this was creating issues with the buffer method. Now that I sorted it out it worked perfect. Thank you both for your help Joseph and @user3338197, it is much appreciated! I learned a lot from it. Have a good day.

Comment: @D.Sanders - Glad you got your problem sorted :)